# How can I add in Typescript typings for AngularJS $q and $http?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

In my code I have this:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../scripts/typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />

angular.module('question')
    .controller('QuestionHomeController', [
        '$http',
        'enumService',
        '$q',
        '$rootScope',
        '$scope',
        '$state',
        questionHomeController]);

function questionHomeController(
    $http,
    enumService,
    $q,
    $rootScope,
    $scope,
    $state
    ) {
```

Can someone tell me how I can add Typescript typing for the $http and the $q?  I already reference the AngularJS type definition files but the typings still do not show up

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you have the typings included in your project, you just need to use it as the type for the variables, so that you get the properties/functions on that type show up on the intellisense.

```
angular.module('question')
    .controller('QuestionHomeController', [
        '$http',
        'enumService',
        '$q',
        '$rootScope',
        '$scope',
        '$state',
        questionHomeController]);

function questionHomeController(
    $http : ng.IHttpService,
    enumService,
    $q: ng.IQService,
    $rootScope : ng.IRootScopeService,
    $scope : ng.IScope,
    $state : ng.ui.IStateService
    ) {
```

Similarly you can also specify the interface type for the service example `for enumService`. Also you can extend the existing types as well. For example your scope has its own function and you use scope as your viewModel then:-

```
interface IquestionHomeViewModel extends ng.IScope {
        func1(arg:string):void;
        ...

}
```

and you would use it as:-

```
$scope : IquestionHomeViewModel ,
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Can you tell me where I can get the ng.ui.IStateService.  Everything works for me except this one.

Comment: @Alan oh what is $state? I thought is was angular ui router state service that you are using? If so you would need to download `angular-ui-router.d.ts` typing file for $state and any other ui router entities.

Comment: Yes. If you are using any other components other than core angular you would need to include its own typings.